# Update collection without postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my application i am showing a list of records in a grid and each record has a link to update the status of the record. This grid resides inside a user control.

I would like to update the collection when user clicks the link without doing the postback.

### Main.aspx

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateFRStatus(int key)
{            
    ManagePartnerConfigurationNew pageObj = new ManagePartnerConfigurationNew();
    pageObj.UpdateFRStatusforAjax(key);
}
```

### ucFR.ascx

```
public void UpdateFRStatus(int key)
{
    //Code here to update the collection.
}

//Javascript for ajax call
<script>
function statusImageClick(Key) {
        
        //ajax call to update the grid with the updated/inserted data.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Main.aspx/UpdateFRStatus',
                 data: '{key : "' + Key + '"}',
       ....
 }
</script>
```

If i move the **UpdateFRStatus()** to **Main.aspx** and make it static everything works fine. but i want to keep this method inside the user control to make the code separation.

Can you please suggests me any way i can update the collection without doing the postback.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You Will not get any reference to The Page or usercontrol without doing a postback and loading it back into state.

Pagemethods Works for pages and not usrcontrols. 
 you could send enough data to The pagemethod to Update The given Entry, (for example key and statusname) then Return data to Update The UI clientside

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way you can directly invoke `UpdateFRStatus` method of the User Control because it can never be exposed as the entry point for the application.

Though, for maintaining the division of labor and all that stuff, you can keep the static method in Main.aspx. You can do something like following:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void UpdateFRStatus(int key)
{
    ucFRObject.UpdateFRStatus(key);
}
```

Where `ucFRObject` is some object of `ucFR` User control that you have added on `Main.aspx`.

Which is essentially the same as what you are doing right now.

Comment: ucFRObject is null if do something like this.

Comment: I am not aware what actual variables you are using; that was just a dummy variable I had made up to explain the steps.

Comment: if make an object of usercontrol inside the main page this object will always be null.